# Write a POST button in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, post, input

I have a simple HTML post with a php variable included as the value, I wish to use this in my codeigniter project what is the best way to do this.

Here is my correct code (I do have the form helper)

```
 <form action="https://www.mysite.co.uk/1/" method="POST">
     <input id="start-test" type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($userID); ?>;
     <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" role="button" id=""></input>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question with my first answer.

If all you want is a post button, then you can write this

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" value="Send" />
```

Or use the form helper

```
 <?php echo form_submit('BtnName', 'Send'); ?>
// Would produce:<input type="submit" name="BtnName" value="Send" />
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_submit

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are doing:

```
<input id="start-test" type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($userID); ?>">
```

Or use set_value like this:

```
<input id="start-test" type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo set_value('userid', $userID); ?>">
```

This will repopulate the field value on form error. I have missed off the HTML special chars but you can include that still if you feel like you need to, but I presume this is an id from a database, that is set with auto increment and as it is not user generated data the use of html special chars here might be a bit unnecessary.

In your controller you can access the post variables like this:

```
$posted_id = $this->input->post('userid');
```

However, you should be using form validation on posted data. This is quite a big topic but you can read about the above in the docs. Also referring to your User ID directly is not always a great solution since this form can be easily manipulated. You can help to alleviate that somewhat with CI CSRF protection and using form_open but it is often best to use sessions and get the ID from there. You should not ever have to include a user id in a hidden form variable.

Set Value 
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#re-populating-the-form

Reading post variables 
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#accessing-form-data

Form Validation in general
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#form-validation

Form open and CSRF
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open

CI Sessions
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-library

If you are not familiar with security practices it is sometimes best to get to know and use a mature and developed authorization and authentication library. There are many so I will not recommend one here. Just do a search for one and find one that suits your needs.